# Intuition about the definition of Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, intuition, density-function

My math book and lector uses the following definition for a PDF,

*A function p from interval $I  ⊆ \mathbb{R}$, that follows*

$$\int_{l}p(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1(x \in I )p(x)dx=1$$
*is called a Probability Density function of I in this case.*

But im not sure i understand the intuition about this , i know the area under the integral is supposed to be 1, and i can see from the definition that it uses an indicator function. But what is p(x) in this case and why do we multiply it by the indicator function?

Many times it seems people just define it as this $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx=1$$

Without the indicator function, and just p(x) .

I searched up on google and it seems like no one else uses this definition, so i hope someone knowledgeable in this area can help me understand it a bit better.

Comment: If $p(x)$ is only supported on $I$, then there's simply no need for the indicator and it can be safely omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval $I$ you refer to is commonly called the *support* of the random variable $X$ and is denoted as $I=\operatorname{supp}(X)$. The support simple refers to the region (in this case subset of the real line) where the density of $X$ takes on positive values. Even if a probability density has support on only a subset of the real line, e.g. $X\sim\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ implies $\operatorname{supp}(X)=[0,1]$, we can always define it as a density on the entire real line with the use of indicator functions. Going back to our example, let $f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\operatorname B(\alpha,\beta)}$ denote the beta density function for which $\int_0^1f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx=1$. By redefining our density function as $f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\operatorname B(\alpha,\beta)} 1_{x\in[0,1]}$ we may formally extend our density to the entire real line without changing any of its properties. In particular, we can now rightfully claim
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx=1,
$$
since $1_{x\in[0,1]}=0$ outside the interval $[0,1]$.

**Edit:**

This is meant to further clarify the OP's follow-up questions. In many statistics texts it is common to see the author(s) state the property
$$
\tag{1}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm dx=1,
$$
where $p(x)$ is some arbitrary probability density function. Note that such an expression does not explicitly mention the support of the density function $p(x)$. So despite the integral in $(1)$ taking place over the entire real line, it is implicitly assumed that all contributions to the integral outside the densities support are zero. For example, if $p(x)$ is the normal density function then $p(x)$ has support everywhere on the real line and so $(1)$ is simply telling us
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx=1.
$$
If, however, the density has support on only a subset of the real line then the expression given by $(1)$ assumes there are "instructions" baked into the equation for the density function that specify where to integrate. Take for example our beta distribution again. Letting $p(x)$ be the $\operatorname{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ density the equation $(1)$ **only makes sense if** we write
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\operatorname B(\alpha,\beta)} 1_{x\in[0,1]}\,\mathrm dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\operatorname B(\alpha,\beta)}\,\mathrm dx=1.
$$

Comment: But what values can p(x) take? If its multiplied by either 1 or 0 in the indicator function, then it wouldnt make sense for p(x) to take $0 \leq p(x)$ because how would the integral equal to 1 then?

Comment: @Emilio I'm not sure what you're asking. In my beta distribution example, I made it so the indicator function is one whenever $x\in[0,1]$ and zero otherwise. So, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^1 f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^\infty f_X(x;\alpha,\beta)\,\mathrm dx=0+1+0=1$, which is what we want the result to be. Multiplying the beta density by one on the interval $x\in[0,1]$ does nothing to the value of the density function on its support.

Comment: Could you describe p(x) as an indicator function as well?

Comment: @Emilio I am hoping my edit clears up your confusion on indicator functions.

Comment: I see but can one just do integral from -∞ to ∞ and just have p(x) be a piecewise function that does the restrictions and stuff to make the integral equal 1 in a simple case?

Comment: @Emilio Sure. Here's a simple example. Let $p(x)=x1_{x\in[0,1]}+1_{x\in[1,3/2]}$ be our density function. Then, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x1_{x\in[0,1]}+1_{x\in[1,3/2]}\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^{3/2}\,\mathrm dx=1/2+1/2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like their way of dealing with random variables that have zero probability in certain regions.  For example, a uniform distribution might be defined to be $\frac{1}{3}$ on the interval $[4,7]$ and $0$ everywhere else.  You can write in that case $\int_{4}^{7} p(x) dx = 1$, or you can say that $I$ is the indicator function for $[4,7]$, and say that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} I\cdot p(x) dx = 1$$ where $p(x) = \frac{1}{3}$.

Some deal with that by simply defining $p(x)$ to be $0$ outside of the interval and $\frac{1}{3}$ on the interval, and integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: And is there a reason that in the definition $\int_{7}^{4}p(x)dx = 1$ would be only $\int_{l}p(x)dx = 1$ ? Why is there only the lower bound I ?

Comment: "Some deal with that by simply defining $p(x)$ to be $0$ outside of the interval and $\frac{1}{3}$ on the interval, and integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$." I guess defining p(x) to be an indicator function could be used for this as well? Or a piecewise function right? Do you have an example of this?

Comment: $p(x)$ is the probability density, not an indicator.  If you define p(x) piecewise over the entire real line, then you can just integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x) dx$.  If you define $p(x) = \frac{1}{3}$ everywhere on the real line, then you need an indicator function to multiply it and "trim it down" by multiplying by zero outside the domain or "support" of the probability density you actually want, in this case $[4,7]$.

Comment: Yeah thank you thats what i figured so, i see most of the time people do it where they define p(x) piecewise and in my case our school defines it with indicator functions instead. Is that correct that the piecewise is mostly used?

Answer (score 1):

The indicator function is defined as  $$1_I=\begin{cases} 1 & x\in I \\ 0 & x\notin I\end{cases}$$

So, when we define $p$ *only* on the set $I$ (using $p(x)1_I$), we see $$\int_\Bbb R 1_Ip(x)dx=\int_Ip(x)dx+\int_{\Bbb R/I}0 dx=\int_Ip(x)dx$$